# how to copy a part of image to another with OpenCV?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a model that predicts the human face segmentation.

[image: image description]

But unfortunately the model is not trained to predict the hair with the face. So now I have the above images as numpy arrays. Is it possible to add the hair from the original photo (The one on the left) to the prediction mask (in the middle) or directly to the result prediction (the one on the right) ?

Basically I just need to deal with the original image to get a little bit from the head above the prediction mask and add it to the prediction so that way at least I'll have a part of the hair in the result.

The code used to create the previous figure:

```
fn = "images/beard.jpg"
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(fn), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im = auto_downscaling(im)

# vgg_preprocess: output BGR channel w/ mean substracted.
inp_im = vgg_preprocess(im)

# Predicting the face segmentation
out = model.predict([inp_im])

out_resized = cv2.resize(np.squeeze(out), (im.shape[1],im.shape[0]))
out_resized_clipped = np.clip(out_resized.argmax(axis=2), 0, 1).astype(np.float64)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(out_resized_clipped, (7,7), 6)


plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.subplot("131")
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(im)
plt.subplot("132")
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(out_resized_clipped, cmap='gray')
plt.subplot("133")
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow((mask[:,:,np.newaxis]*im.astype(np.float64)).astype(np.uint8))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate what you want i tested this. First I create some function to create similar sized images from the inputs.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def resize(img, dim=(300, 300)):
    # perform the actual resizing of the image and show it
    frame = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    return frame
```

Then read and resize the images separately

```
img1 = resize(cv2.imread('img1.png'))
img2 = resize(cv2.imread('img2.png'))
dst = cv2.addWeighted(img1,0.7,img2,0.3,0)
```

The `cv2.addWeighted` function will helps me achieve the result.
then you can do as you need with the output

```
cv2.imwrite('out.png', dst)
```

So Applying this same principle to your code would be something like. I see that you have similar sized images there.

```
fn = "images/beard.jpg"
im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(fn), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im = auto_downscaling(im)

# vgg_preprocess: output BGR channel w/ mean substracted.
inp_im = vgg_preprocess(im)

# Predicting the face segmentation
out = model.predict([inp_im])

out_resized = cv2.resize(np.squeeze(out), (im.shape[1],im.shape[0]))
out_resized_clipped = np.clip(out_resized.argmax(axis=2), 0, 1).astype(np.float64)
out_resized_clipped = cv2.GaussianBlur(out_resized_clipped, (7,7), 6)

mask = cv2.addWeighted(out_resized, 0.7, out_resized_clipped,0.3,0)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(out_resized_clipped, (7,7), 6)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.subplot("131")
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(im)
plt.subplot("132")
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(out_resized_clipped, cmap='gray')
plt.subplot("133")
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow((mask[:,:,np.newaxis]*im.astype(np.float64)).astype(np.uint8))
```

Comment: Hi Man, I really appreciate your help .. I got your code but I got this error
`mask = cv2.addWeighted(out_resized, 0.7, out_resized_clipped,0.3,0)
cv2.error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op` I don't understand what's that?

Comment: sorry, about that. seems the image data is not an array as stated in the error. but what happens if you type cv2.imwrite('img1.png', out_resized) before the line assigning mask? @AhmedEssam

Comment: wait again, please use a general resize function to create uniform sized images this may help.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your comment?! what should I do?

Comment: am not sure yet but, i used that to merge two image fragments in some project before. except images must be of same dimesions